# Should I update my question's code to include the correct answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, answers, code

When a question is solved, should the OP edit the post to include the working solution provided by one of the answers?

Here's an example:

Codeaddict gave me the correct answer [for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406662/why-am-i-returning-empty-records-when-querying-in-mysql-with-php). I accepted his answer and I also upvoted a helpful comment.

Should I also update my question's code to include his correction?

Answer (score 18):

Nope.  You should just do what you did and accept the answer that helped you.  Changing the code will screw up the context of the question.

Answer (score 6):

No, don't change your original question but some people add an "Edit" or "Update" section at the end of their answer. It's not strictly necessary but you can add the fixed code to the end of your question (clearly marked as an addendum/solution).

Comment: did you mean "question" instead of "answer" in the first sentence?