# Suggested edits - comment smuggling

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

Phenomenon: **A low rep user uses suggested edit to add a comment to an answer\question.**

Is anyone else seeing this?

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/1832

Comment: Linking for other users as they come in here: a similar phenomenon of [people "smuggling" answers into edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77771/suggested-edits-that-add-an-answer-to-the-question), in which this kind of comment was discussed in a tangent.

Comment: "comment smuggling" - chuckles :)

Comment: I continue to see this when reviewing suggested edits. Has there been any progress toward a solution? (It seems like a good idea to raise the required rep for suggested edits higher than that for comments, or at least to make it obvious to new users why they can't comment...)

Comment: I'm also seeing a lot of this - and I'm new to reviewing... http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/203343

Answer (score 7):

wow.  Makes me glad we're approving these edits.  Sounds like the user interface may need to be tweaked if this is happening often.

Users shouldn't see the edit button and think, "I need to communicate with this guy, and this seems to be the best/only place to do it", before seeing the comment or answer button.

On the other hand, new users are limited - they can't provide comments anyway.

I wonder if we should raise the suggest edit to at or above the comment level?

Comment: More and more I'm becoming convinced that we need to enable comments for everyone.  They can be flagged and managed easily enough, but the fact that people are using answers and edit suggestions as a means to communicate is frustrating. Still on the fence about it though, as the primary interface of SO is questions and answers.

Comment: @Pol You make an interesting point re. raising the rep. I think there is a case for users earning a minimal amount of rep so that they at least get some idea of how things work by expending some effort. They also then have something to lose.

Comment: @polly no, we won't be doing that. Would just lead to noise, read the part about comments here: http://goofygrin.wordpress.com/2011/02/01/why-stackoverflow-sucks-and-participating-there-is-impossible/

Comment: @Jeff - Oh that's a classic, awesome blog post!  Thanks for the link, I'll be chuckling for awhile now...

Comment: @Jeff I think the fact that he has closed the comments on his blog post is a tad ironic...

Comment: :-) @Jeff, some Trevor comments on that blog *"But it required high ‘rep’ because there were more than 20 answers already"* I guess that refers to a protected question? Or are new users never allowed to add answers when 20 have already been posted?

Comment: Its rediculous however, that you can *edit* existing material, and *create answers* and *Create questions*, all of which are far far noisier than commnets, but you can't comment, and enabling comments will help syphon the noise to the right place.

Comment: But I'd agree we'd need better comment moderation if that were to happen, just to prevent comments being the new target for link-spam.