# Are users who have a suggested edit rejected valid targets for @comment replies?

Tags: support, comment-replies, suggested-edits

After reading [Suggested edits that add an answer to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77771/suggested-edits-that-add-an-answer-to-the-question), linked in the comments was a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1832) that was rejected. I thought I'd leave a comment to the new user who suggested it so they would know what happened, why the edit was rejected, and how to ask a new question:

> @OFG: Your [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-suggestions/1832) was rejected because it really is another question and doesn't improve this answer. Use the [`AskQuestion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button to ask a new question. Feel free to include a `link` to this answer if it helps others understand your new question.

But I don't think the @ ping will work, since that user is not in the edit history as an editor. Are users that make suggested edits valid targets of @pinging from that post in the same way editors of the post are?

Answer (score 10):

This is tricky, I would like to use this system to teach people.

Part of teaching is giving feedback beyond approving or rejecting an edit. When we reject edits we do not notify, there is no way of leaving comments and @replies do not work.

However, comments on the post that teach the suggester how to edit have nothing to do with the post, so they clearly do not belong on the post.

Do we need commenting on the suggested-edit permalink page? Perhaps. If we add that it would complicate things and is yet another area for us to moderate.

Comment: Maybe not full commenting (with replies etc.), but *only* (optional?) accept/reject comments, just like revision comments? (This would only be useful if there will be some overview that links to the permalinks though, like in a user profile? Otherwise most people won't know where to find the edits they proposed to start with.)

Comment: Do we really need accept comments? And there should be a topbar notification for rejects; people should know they've been rejected and learn from it. That's the point of the suggested edits feature after all - to let low-rep users learn what the community considers an acceptable edit.

Comment: Related feature request: [Possibility to add a comment to a rejected suggested edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79088/possibility-to-add-a-comment-to-a-rejected-suggested-edit).

Comment: As explained in [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections), sometimes one might need some investigation to find that an edit is spam or otherwise wrong, and one might like to pass that thoughts to the second reviewer? The same might apply to approvals, @bdonlan. Surely all very optional. (I know, spam should ALSO be reported by flagging some other post, and explaining the thing.)

Answer (score -1):

I don't think we want comments saying way edits were rejected, as the commnet is only of value to one person and should be a private message.

Comment: @comments are targeted to a single person already (and with the permalink to the suggested edit, everyone can reference the conversation). Also, I don't think we want to get into private messaging `:)`

Comment: This would've been a brilliant answer had it not for the fact that the private message `[feature-request]` has been shot down to pieces on Meta already