# improve the title of pending edits

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

[image]

---

The counter says that there are 0 pending edits while there is actually 1 pending edit according the title. It was [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901905/lightbox-not-working-on-ie8). I could just open and review it. It's maybe related to the fact that this is the 2nd suggested edit by the same user.

---

**Update** as per Michael Mrozek's answer it turns out to be the amount of approvals on the edit: can't the title be little expanded? E.g. "This edit has *n* approvals" which would in turn make the `(0)` part more sense (it initially didn't make sense to me).

Comment: may take a while to deploy though ... I have a lot of stuff in flux on local

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That number appears to actually be the number of votes the edit has (approvals and rejections); so `(0)` means there's a suggested edit with no votes, `(1)` means there's a suggested edit with one vote (either approved or rejected), and `(2)` means the suggested edit has one approve vote and one reject vote  (since it only takes two in one category to take effect). A suggested edit blocks further edits, so there can never be multiple edits in the queue for a single post

Comment: @BalusC I said exactly the opposite about a week ago in a comment; I thought it was edits in the queue too. Unfortunately now I can't find that comment anymore to correct it

Comment: I turned the bug report into a feature request wrt the title, it would otherwise be an utterly useless question. Glad to see that I'm not the only one who initially interpreted it differently though.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Actually it is a bit more subtle, the number represents the total score.</strike>

You may see 1, 0 or -1 on Stack Overflow. 1 means that one person approve, 0 could mean that one approved and one rejected. -1 means that one person rejected.

I fixed it so it counts total votes and shows what happened in the tooltip.

Comment: Fix confirmed. That's indeed more clear now. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't realize this was the intended behavior; it doesn't seem to work. I see the number of votes, like I just voted to reject an edit so the link says `edit (1)`. Yesterday I saw one where there was one vote to approve and one vote to reject, and it said `edit (2)`

Comment: @Michael sorry I forgot to strike out the old way it worked