# Approving / rejecting proposed edits should allow entering a reason

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections)

It would be great to be able to enter a reason when approving or rejecting a proposed edit. There would be two benefits: other reviewers would read it and agree or disagree, and the editor would learn the rules of editing.

For instance: Sometimes I reject edits when someone corrects another ones answer (not only in grammar or formatting, but in the statement). He may be right, but he should put it into a comment or write his own answer. I would reject it and write "Please write this into a comment rather then changing the answer".

I saw such edits being approved. If there would be comments, even the reviewers would learn from each other and the reviews would become more consistent. (If others don't agree with my judgment in the above case, I will stop rejecting such edits. etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I also see edits like this a lot, and they're usually approved.

Although I like the comment idea, I think we should work towards determining standard reject reasons, like with flag widget. It'll eliminate repetition and you won't have to worry that somebody will approve edit while you're typing :)

Also, having some clarification for what edits are welcome might help. Currently, even [edit section in privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) is very vague about it. You can't blame 100-rep users for not following the rules, if you do not specify them first.

Comment: Yes, a standard set of reject reasons would be good. "Changed original poster's intent" "Added commentary" "Unconstructive delete" etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree, standard reasons would be great in many cases. Although I think that there may be many cases which need a specific explanation or advise from the reviewer. Standard cases may be an 80% solution.