# How to deal with suggested edits that change content?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, comment-replies

I just rejected this [suggested edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/474) on Meta. It was just removing an entire paragraph from an answer.  The paragraph was the last of three from the answer and was important.

Is there a way to leave a comment reply somewhere, or contact the suggester in some other way to let them know that suggested edits are to improve not remove content from posts?

*Note: I guess this might be a side effect of edit timings by the original answerer and the suggest but even in that case what did Roy want to change?*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I talked about this with Jeff this week.

The plan is to allow people to optionally leave comments on rejects so we can help teach people how to edit. Not implemented yet.

Comment: Comments for the editor, right? For the 2-person-approval on SO, I guess you know there's also a few requests for comments directed to the future 2nd or 3rd reviewer, which could then also apply to approvals. So, just in case you missed that: [Approving / rejecting proposed edits should allow entering a reason](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79517/approving-rejecting-proposed-edits-should-allow-entering-a-reason-closed)

Comment: Good. This is something I've been thinking/wondering about.