# Editing does not work for me anymore, but no warning at all

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I am trying to make some edits to other's questions but my modifications won't be saved anymore.

I have done some editing everyday since it is a "Social Service" and at the same time "Easy Money". But that suddenly stopped working. Changes are not being stored, and there is no "your edit will be peer-reviewed" message. And unlike others, I do **not** get a warning such as "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." either.

Is there a limitation for this action or I have done something wrong?

Comment: Hm, strange. So your changes are not being stored, and there is no "your edit will be peer-reviewed" message?

Comment: That's exactly what is happening ..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many of your suggested edits were rejected yesterday. That could make your edit suggest privileges a week off.

[image]

Basically, you did some posts making some keywords bold, that's not welcome by the community.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I am not complaining. But, I will appreciate if I get told about it to not make me feel as I've been shut down :D

Comment: @Akram, those suggested edits approve/reject are done by different users, so they don't know how many posts of yours are rejected.

Comment: The system could be more verbose about this though.

Comment: @Akram, if I am right, then this would simply no longer show the edit link, and/or give you a "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." error [like described here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87123/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-message-is-not-integrated-into-the-page). But it seems to me this is *not* what is happening?

Comment: @YOU, that comment makes no sense to me at all. Who does "they" refer to? How would The System not know?

Comment: @Arjan, the "They" I mean is "Users who rejected his edits.", not system. Of course System can know but I don't know there is warning system or not.

Comment: @Arjan: A "Too many edits have been rejected .." message will be fine. I felt as the power is off and I haven't save my modifications. You know that feeling...

Comment: @Akram, do you also know the feeling of people, who need to rollback your edits? - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5767146/revisions

Comment: Nice find, @YOU, that is bad approval then too. Oddly, [it's a single-vote approval](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/35926). I didn't know that worked on SO?

Comment: @You: Yes I do.. They need a better mouses with more sensetive buttons. I appreciate all the efforts that are done in this community. All I was asking for is some more notifications.

Comment: @Arjan, that's owner approve. and he proposed two times to same post, first one get rejected - http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/35925

Comment: Then it's a bad rollback ;-) Though I do dislike inappropriate `<strong>` (bold) **formatting**, *a lot*. @Akram, I'm guessing that's also why your edits were rejected: no need to go into extremes there!

Comment: @Arjan, Nope, it is still not bad rollback, for me at least, he suggested twice, owner rejected once but he suggested again with just bold part, I think owner just gave him a chance, but community did not.

Comment: I dislike strong formatting too if it's not that of the OP, but putting function names into backticks is perfectly fine IMO.

Comment: @Akram, getting feedback about your edits [is on its way](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88445/how-to-deal-with-suggested-edits-that-change-content/88446#88446). Still then, the current system should have shown you the "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days." rather than silently not save anymore.

Comment: And that post reject was in the middle of continuous rejects - http://i.imgur.com/zTs26.png - so some people might think "this guy edits were not good enough, I might need to rollback all to save the internet" :-)

Comment: @YOU: your point is clear. I think mine is too.

Comment: I still think it's a bug, @Akram!

Comment: @Arjan, you mean I am a "bug"? I got ["bug" badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/81/bug) recently also.

Comment: There is a bug badge...? :-) Anyway: given there was no warning, I think that such is a bug. The reason for the "ban" is clear, but even then it should have shown that "Too many of your edits were rejected, try again in 7 days.".

Comment: @Arjan, agree, probably make edit button visible, and when they click edit button, that msg should be displayed.

Comment: He, you need more bold! I totally missed that "Basically, you did some posts making some keywords bold, that's not welcome by the community." between the screenshots in your answer!

Comment: The error message [does already exist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87123/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-message-is-not-integrated-into-the-page), but this user was not shown that message. Anyway, I'll just retag this, let the developers figure it out ;-)

Comment: @Arjan, heh, bold is kind of ALL CAPS on some people feeling I think. and I didn't know about the msg already exist. Thanks.

Comment: There **YOU** have it. [YOUR POST IS USED AS A BAD EXAMPLE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88756/can-we-get-rid-of-the-default-text-enter-image-description-here). And **rightfully** so! ;-)

Comment: @Arjan 2.5 years later, dev decided it wasn't a bug after all... and I voted to close as "can't reproduce any longer" as it's now showing disabled edit link with the explanation as a tooltip. :)