# What's the point in adding alt-text to an image?

Tags: discussion, markdown, images, accessibility, alt-text

When you add an image to a post via the helper bar, you get this:

`![enter image description here][1]`

`[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ve8n0.png`

What purpose does the *enter image description here* text serve? I've not noticed any way of seeing this text, except if I view the page source for the post.

Comment: This is an exhaustive explanation written by a web developer with vision impairment: [Alt-texts: The Ultimate Guide](https://axesslab.com/alt-texts/)

Comment: Related: [tag accessibility](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accessibility) and *[Guidance for providing image content descriptions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378006/)*

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `alt` (alternative) attribute is used when the image fails to load, or for user agents that can't display images (screen readers, very old mobile browsers, etc.)

According to the [HTML5 specifications](http://developers.whatwg.org/embedded-content-1.html#alt),

> The most general rule to consider when writing alternative text is the following: **the intent is that replacing every image with the text of its alt attribute not change the meaning of the page.**

This means that the "image description" hint is actually not very accurate. If the image is not important (in the sense that describing it will not help readers), is purely decorative, or if its content is already described by the surrounding text, then the attribute should actually be left blank.

Whatever you do, **do not** leave the placeholder text in, since that is worse than leaving it blank.

---

If you need a tooltip, you can use the `title` attribute. In Markdown, use

```
![alt text][1] 

 [1]: http://example.com/image "Your Title Here"
```

or

```
![alt text](http://example.com/image "Your Title Here")
```

For example,

[image]

the same format is used for titles on links, [like this.](https://placekitten.com/170/300)

Comment: +1 for the last sentence - if you don't have meaningful short description of the image, better leave it blank.

Comment: Unfortunately on these sites the alt-text might [not show nicely](http://i.stack.imgur.com/uIhkE.png), due to the line height, I guess. ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox/71453#71453))

Comment: @Arjan that might be why I've never seen it! It would make more sense to make it a tool-tip?

Comment: @Pureferret No, it's not a good idea to display the `alt` text as a tooltip, since if you follow what the specs say the tooltip would just repeat the contents of the image. If you need a tooltip, that's what the `title` attribute is for.

Comment: @pur, you can also specify the `title` in Markdown.

Comment: I'm sure a search would have shown you, @pur. But Tim already explained too. That said: I am on mobile, no hover hence no tooltip either.

Answer (score 13):

The `alt` attribute is also used by people with eyesight problems who have difficulty seeing images so is not just a fallback.

So emphasises the  text that @TimYiJiang gave from the HTML5 specification

> The most general rule to consider when writing alternative text is the following: the intent is that replacing every image with the text of its alt attribute not change the meaning of the page.

Comment: There have been more than one blind user come through the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: IMHO, this is the most important answer.  Upvoted.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what the others said, it's also good for searching purposes. Search engines like Google can pinpoint the subject of a picture much more accurately if there's a description in the alt text, than when they have to guess the subject from the context.

Answer (score 1):

It adds the [alt-text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute), which is basically a fallback if there is an issue fetching the image. If the image is not found, it'll show a white box with the alt-text in it.

On IE, the alt-text also gives a something similar to a `title`{*} tooltip, though this doesn't work on Chrome (or, IIRC, Firefox).

So it works exactly as it was intended.

*<sup>Curiously, webcomics still call it the "alt-text", even though they don't use the `alt` attribute. Remnants of a long-lost civilization when everyone used either IE or Netscape, I suppose :S</sup>

Comment: Many work places block imgur domain so it's pretty relevant indeed - when users browse from such places they'll only see the alternative text as all images will be broken..

Comment: As an aside: even IE9 still (erroneously) shows alt-text on mouse hover, unless a (empty) title is present as well.

Comment: @Arjan only with quirks mode pages!

Comment: @MrL, I cannot validate now, but I saw it yesterday in what I think was a valid HTML5 page... But then, IE's F12 developer tools have fooled me before, so maybe it was actually in IE8 or IE7 mode...

Comment: Ah, @MrLister, you're right: [all](http://jsbin.com/ulamak/1/) is fine in IE8 and IE9, if they're not somehow fooled into the wrong mode. Thanks.