# Could image description be input in the Add Image dialog box while uploading images?

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader, accessibility, alt-text

When uploading an image, could there be a field to input the caption inside the dialog box? This could work so that as the user waits for the file to upload, he could be typing the caption.

> [image: Add Image pop up box]

Then when the following is generated, it would have something other than "enter image description here".
`![enter image description here][1]`

Comment: That's not really a caption, just alternative text showing in case the image is unavailable.

Comment: Are you referring to `![image caption](<image URL>)` or `![image][1] [1]: <image URL> "image caption"`?

Comment: @Werner first, if I understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Troyen, it fringed my ears too, but apparently *inputted* is ok: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30684/21975

Comment: @brasofilo I know it's _technically_ okay, but it was in the title and I think more people are familiar with the simpler form above.  I did a quick search before editing and the general consensus all around seemed to be "yes, inputted is valid, _but_..."

Comment: @Celeritas, I've made an edit to your question to exemplify Werner's point, the markup result is http://i.stack.imgur.com/MlzZi.png The [`alt` attribute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_attribute)  is used to *describe* the image, and the `title` to show a tooltip when you hover the image. See [HTML img tag: title attribute vs. alt attribute?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/872389/1287812)

Answer (score 16):

I think this is a great idea.

With the current implementation, this tool, which is the most convenient way to add images to posts, leads to a default behavior of not including an alt-text, which is an [important](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144080/whats-the-point-in-adding-alt-text-to-an-image) element for readers who are visually impaired as well as for search-ability. Once the user has finished using the tool, the image is added, and the only prompt to add alt-text is some text in the post's markdown code that, most users will likely assume, will never be read by anyone. As a result, there is very little incentive and a little bit of extra friction to adding an alt-text, and therefore, [most of the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/247785/179), it doesn't happen.

This tool should include a text-entry box for alt-text, accompanied with some explanation along the lines of what is currently in the [Markdown help for images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images):

> The word in square brackets is the alt text, which gets displayed if the browser can't show the image. Be sure to include meaningful alt text for screen-reading software.

The explanation should link to [more](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/21518/how-detailed-should-a-text-alternative-version-of-an-image-be) information [about](http://www.abilitynet.org.uk/blog/five-golden-rules-compliant-alt-text) what should go in the alt text.

The alt-text field should be required, but there should be a checkbox labeled "Leave alt-text blank. This image contains no information," which, if checked, disables the alt-text field and makes it not-required.

While we're at it, it might make sense to also add an optional field for "[Tooltip](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3430/2)," so the user can do the entire image-entry process in one step, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, write the alt-text first, highlight it, then upload an image. The alt-text will be enclosed as.. the alt-text of the image.

Example:

1. Write `Add image pop up box`
2. Highlight it
3. Click the image uploader button and upload the image
4. The result will be `![Add image pop up box][1]`<sup>1</sup>

<sup>1</sup> Technically, it's `[![Add image pop up box][1]][1]` since the feature update to automatically link to the original image

Comment: No, the default needs to be changed. It is not difficult to change the text, but people just don't bother to change the caption. That is the power of defaults at play..