# Stop image upload completion from stealing cursor focus

Tags: feature-request, images, uploader, alt-text

Upon image upload completion, the cursor focus is moved to the image tag (see example below). Feature request: don't move the cursor focus.

[image]

Answer (score 14):

#### The cursor focus is moved to the image tag

That, in my opinion, is the correct behaviour, as it reminds you to complete the image tag.

This is important for visually impaired or blind users who are using screen readers:

> Use semantic HTML markup for structures such as headings, paragraphs, lists, forms, and tables. **Provide text alternatives for images**, icons, and other non-text content. Ensure keyboard compatibility, and ensure that text information is understandable without the visual context.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Source: [Text to Speech | Web Accessibility Initiative (WAI) | W3C](https://www.w3.org/WAI/perspective-videos/speech/)

---

#### Further Reading

- [What's the point in adding alt-text to an image? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144080/whats-the-point-in-adding-alt-text-to-an-image)
- [How can I write good alt text? - Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/332006/how-can-i-write-good-alt-text)
- [Axess Lab | Alt-texts: The Ultimate Guide](https://axesslab.com/alt-texts/)
- [Guidance for providing image content descriptions - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/378006/guidance-for-providing-image-content-descriptions)

Comment: Sadly it doesn't really help, 99.999% of the users never add description. :/

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars and some uses like myself type a few random characters in the image tag before realizing the cursor moved to the image tag.

Comment: While it’s a noble goal to make users add image descriptions, this shouldn’t happen _in the middle_ of typing something else. Missing image descriptions should be dealt with with a more carefully designed UI and UX. Maybe consider GitHub’s design which takes the file name as an alt text.

Comment: @SebastianSimon could also explore automated image captioning.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars [What percentage of images on SE have a meaningful alt-text?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386172/178179)