# Leave message to edit suggestor from edit approver about more improvements they could have made?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I think it would be a good idea to have an option for people reviewing suggested edits to leave a comment to the users who suggested the edits.

This would be useful for helping the newer users to learn how to edit better.

Example:

- *Thanks for the edit, but for next time remove the "I hope it's not a duplicate" as it doesn't add anything to the question*

This is more useful for approved/improved edits as you may think the edit improves the question but more should've been done in the edit and you should let the editor know what other things they should look out for to improve for next time.

Comment: @random I don't think this is a duplicate because that question was about improvement suggestions on rejected edits, whereas this one is about improvement suggestions on approved/improved edits.

Comment: I think this is a good idea but I also think the field that this comment goes into should be titled "Suggestion(s) for improving your edits:" rather than "Comment:" so that the advice is clearly only the reviewer's thoughts rather than always firm policy.

Often I see comments on questions and answers offering advice about "improvements" that don't quite match site policies and occasionally some that are almost the opposite of them.

Comment: [Approving / rejecting proposed edits should allow entering a reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79517/approving-rejecting-proposed-edits-should-allow-entering-a-reason)

Comment: @random still no dupe, as this one here clearly asks for a way to send direct notification, not only leave a reason visible upon seeing the review item.

Comment: As for the request here, comment would be too intrusive, and pollute the post itself. Notification can work.

Comment: How many times does this actually occur? I doubt it is worth it. If an edit is not (good) enough, someone else will come along and further edit the question. And the original editor will just by participating (and maybe even by getting some edits rejected) develop further, without this functionality. There are larger fish to fry.

Comment: @ShadowWizard yeh that's the major issue, i've seen people commenting to editors several times, which although is usually because of rejects, often results in many more comments on the question, derailing the question to be about the edit instead of the actual question

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the comment section that @reply commenting is an option, and that it has the disadvantage of polluting the post comments.

I guess you could invite them to a chat room.

But I agree it would be nice if you could have a more inline/easy way of giving that feedback / showing them how they can do better / even better.

**Here's one option I thought of**: If the reviewer uses the "improve edit" or the "reject-and-edit" option, then send a notification to the suggestor pointing them to the improved/replaced revision page or to the completed review task page.

What I think is nice about this approach is that it just ties together two already existing pieces of machinery: improve/replace edit reviews, and inbox notifications. It sounds kind of easy to implement to me, but that's just my gut and I'm not an SE dev. It does sound like a nice QoL approach as opposed to all the clicks and searches it takes to create a chat room.

@rene made a good point that sometimes reviewers make edit improvements that they wouldn't necessarily expect the edit suggestor to make, so perhaps it would be useful to have a checkbox that says "send notification to suggestor" which is selected by default.

Comment: I think the Reject and Edit option actually already sends a notification to the user who suggested the edit. Having the option to send a message with Improve Edit would be useful but I don't think it should be on by default. In most cases you aren't going to be approving an edit with an issue serious enough that the editor needs to be pinged.

Comment: QoL = [quality of life](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quality_of_life#Noun)