# Allow 10k users to see suggested edit history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, 10k-tools, revisions-list

Often the suggestions fly by so quickly, or I go to approve/decline and it's already been processed by another user, and I want to go back and see what happened to it:

- Was the suggestion accepted or declined?
- Who accepted or declined the suggestion?
- [Why was the suggestion accepted or declined?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections)
- In particular if the edit was declined, I might want to go back and make an edit myself.

The information *does exist* in the system, but it's very inaccessible right now. The only way I know of is to navigate to a specific URL (which I've forgotten) *and* you have to know the internal suggestion id. This isn't a real way of viewing history, hence this request.

I would suggest a page similar to the "see all edits in chronological order" 10k tool, but this is up to the devs, obviously.

**EDIT:** As Michael points out [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82561/can-we-make-suggested-edits-an-actual-page/82567#82567), the page already exists for diamond mods, but isn't exposed to 10k users. That would be the next logical step, IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So everyone knows, you can get to this via a [link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits) on the `links` tab.

<sub>(Also adding this answer so the question doesn't get bumped.)</sub>