# Can we make /suggested-edits an actual page?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

Currently, `/suggested-edits/ID` links us to an individual suggested edit record for posterity and allows us to audit our fellow users' work.

With that in mind, could we make `/suggested-edits` a page in and of itself. We could have it list the fifty most recent suggested edits, something like the following:

```
ID    Post                        Editor      Reviewer      Decision
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123   What is my name?            (anon)      Jeff Atwood   Rejected
122   What is 42?                 user100000  Joel Spolsky  Accepted
121   What is Stack Exchange?     user100000  Community     Accepted (Improved)
```

This way, we can make it really simple to see what the most recent suggested edits were. (I wouldn't support putting it in /tools, since it's already public info if you manually modify the URL).

Comment: Dupe of [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81910/allow-10k-users-to-see-suggested-edit-history) without rep requirement?

Comment: Also, in general, just because it's public info doesn't mean it shouldn't be a 10k tool -- for example, the recently closed questions lists: that's public info, but it's not aggregated in that way for users < 10k.

Comment: @Jon I'm not really sure why though, other than "we like giving 10ks lists of stuff". But given the choice between 10k-only and mod-only, I'd like it to be 10k-only

Answer (score 6):

That page actually already exists, but it's beyond even putting it in `/tools` -- it's only available to mods:

[image: Screenshot of the UL edit suggestion dashboard]

As you said, it's already public info, so I think moving it to `/suggested-edits` makes sense

Comment: I'd request this be a 2K privilege - as with editing today. I'm sure there are lots of people who would like to help out with this task.