# Who can see the rejected/approved edits in review-beta/suggested-edits/history?

Tags: support, review

On Stack Overflow, where I am not a 10K user, I can only see my decisions, on review-beta/suggested-edits/history. On sites where I am a 20K user, I can see decisions made from other users.

Is that caused from my reputation, or is Stack Overflow an exception?

Comment: Here on meta, history says "You have not reviewed any suggested edits yet.", so I think it's the rep.

Comment: @Daniel true, here and in the main site I have 10K+ and see the history, on gaming where I have less than 10K I get same message like yours.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

10K rep is indeed needed, looks like it was implemented at April 2<sup>nd</sup> 2011 and moved along to the new review system as well:

[Allow 10k users to see suggested edit history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81910/allow-10k-users-to-see-suggested-edit-history)

(Or prior to this, can't really tell)