# Does reputation affect what entries I can see in the review queue's history?

Tags: support, reputation, review, review-history

When I look at the [review queue's history for First Posts](https://money.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) (as an example) on a beta site where I have a fair amount of reputation, I see my reviews and those of others.

[image: review queue history, money.SE]

However, if I look at [this same page for another beta site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) where I have less reputation (academia.SE), I only see my reviews.

[image: review queue history, academia.SE]

I also see this on [a graduated site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/history) (travel.SE).

[image: review queue history, travel.SE]

and on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history).

[image: review queue history, SO]

Is there a reputation threshold for seeing reviews by other users in the history tab, or is there another feature/nuance at work that I'm unaware of? If so, where is this defined on the privileges page?

Comment: I believe this is tied to the access to moderator tools privilege.

Comment: @Antony I actually just came to that conclusion while trawling meta.SO for a solution, so I think that's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, this *may* already be answered by [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81910/218097) and [this related post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146922/218097). My guess is that this relates to access to moderator tools, so on graduated sites, users with over 10K rep can see the full review history, while on beta sites, the reputation threshold is 2K for these privileges.