# Give a hint to low-rep question askers when editing answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

I've seen a large increase in the number of edit suggestions from question askers (especially low-rep question askers) that are really intended to be comments on an answer, rather than an edit. In some cases the comments are extended, include additional information, and would best be edits to the original question.

I suggest that a hint be provided to low-rep question owners if they go to edit an answer, something to the effect of

> Are you commenting on this answer? If so, please use the comments feature. If this answer partially helps you but you need to provide additional information, please update your question to include this additional information and leave a comment on this answer to indicate your updates.

These are some recent examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/14343
- https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/15460

Comment: Don't forget that very low rep users can't comment on questions/answers (other than their own). I guess suggested edits are a way to bypass that restriction.

Comment: @Benjol: they can comment on answers to their own questions, however, and this is where the problem is cropping up (that they're not using comments, and instead using edits). The issue is compounded in that we can't provide any feedback when we reject the edit, so the behavior isn't getting discouraged.

Comment: vote this up: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We are now **disallowing answer edits** in this specific situation:

1. You are a new, VERY low rep user
2. You own the question
3. You are attempting to edit an answer to your question

Bear in mind that comment boxes are *pre-expanded* for new users on their own questions (and users with even 1 rep can comment on their own questions and any answers to their questions), so these users are going far out of their way to do the wrong thing.

Now blocked, though.

Comment: Perfect, I think that should reduce some unwanted noise.