# Question on invalid flags and rejected edits

Tags: support, flags, moderation, rejected-edits

Is there a way to know **which are the reasons** for a flag to be marked as invalid or an edit rejected?

-- EDIT --

My decision for this issue is that, given that I can't get an explanation, I'll express my opinion anyway with a downvote.

Comment: Jon's already answered your question about flags. But there's no way to know why a suggested edit was rejected. There's a [feature request here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections) to allow people to add a reason for why they rejected an edit. I think it would be a good idea; I see far too many editors trying to improve the site, but making the same mistakes over and over. If I could leave a comment inline, it'd be way easier than trying to find one of their unrelated posts and tell them why I've rejected 4 of their edits.

Comment: @Cody +1. Thanks for the link, I hope they will implement the proposal; it would be a great opportunity to improve own moderations skill.

Comment: @CodyGray: Ugh, mods will have to give a *reason* why a flag was invalid?  Shouldn't it be *obvious*?  A better solution would be to track how many invalids a user has had and present this to the mod when viewing the flag.  If the mod elects, let them add a short message to the flag that is visible to the user when viewing their flag history.  Requiring a reason every time is just a waste of it.  Letting us communicate with chronic failures ("How exactly is this low quality when it has four upvotes and ten answers???") would be better all around.

Comment: @Will - I wasn't talking about mods and flags so much as rejected edits. Pretty sure that's what the linked feature request is about. If something is so bad that it got flagged for mod attention, it should just be deleted with prejudice, no comments necessary.

Comment: @CodyGray: Sorry, was concentrating on the first bit... "for a **flag to be marked as invalid** or an edit rejected"

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is because it was not what you thought it was. If you flag as "not an answer" and it is marked as invalid, then it really *was* an answer.

When I've asked about this kind of thing in the past I've been told that if you are a bad flagger the mods will email you. Or perhaps just show up in your home when you least expect it. Probably the latter.

Comment: In a bird costume. Let us not forget that.

Comment: Correct on the "Not an Answer" flag. Not an Answer doesn't mean it's a bad answer, it means it's really a comment or a question. No matter how bad an answer might be, it's still an answer if it attempts to answer the question asked.

Comment: @Grace Note: _Friendly_ bird costume (Big Bird from Sesame Street)? Or _evil_ bird costume?

Comment: @Josh http://static2.stuff.co.nz/1303774777/150/4927150.jpg