# Flagging old questions and invalid flags

Tags: discussion, migration, flags, moderation

Hi, recently I flagged as off-topic [a question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/621380/seo-url-structure) that was posted two years ago. The flag has been marked as invalid and I'd greatly appreciate your help to understand why, given that another way to know this apparently [does not exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90203/question-on-invalid-flags-and-rejected-edits) (yet)!

As the question is clearly much more related to enthusiast webmasters than programmers I suggested to move it on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), but I got my flag wight decreased because my flag was marked as invalid. The sole reason I can figure out for this is for the age of the question. Can you confirm my guess? It sounds weird anyway, as other [even older question](https://superuser.com/questions/277805/how-do-i-set-the-desktop-background-on-windows-from-a-script)s have been migrated recently.

I have no clue, do you?

---

#### Reminder from the FAQ: What kind of questions can I ask here?

> **Pro Webmasters - Stack Exchange** is for professional and enthusiast
>   webmasters. If your question generally
>   covers the operation of websites which
>   you control, then you’re in the right
>   place to ask your question!
>
> **Stack Overflow** is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who
>   write code because they love it. We
>   feel the best Stack Overflow questions
>   have a bit of source code in them, but
>   if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem  * a
>     software algorithm  * software tools
>     commonly used by programmers  *
>     matters that are unique to the
>     programming profession
>
> … then you’re in the right place to
>   ask your question!

Comment: just leave it like that ......... imho.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, ordinarily that question should be migrated to Pro Webmasters. However, we don't migrate *old* questions. The new site doesn't want them either. That has been discussed numerous times here already in the context of other sites. See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84395/should-i-flag-ancient-questions-that-need-closing-migrating) and [this other question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83759/migrating-old-so-questions-to-programmers) for more specific details. The consensus seemed to be that it was best to leave them as is on the original site.

So I *assume* what happened is that a moderator marked your flag as invalid because the particular question that you flagged should *not* be migrated to Pro Webmasters.

Yes, the better option would have probably been to mark your flag as valid, while still taking no action. But moderators are human, and they sometimes make mistakes. They might not have thought to do this, or they might have just clicked the wrong button. My suggestion is not to worry so much about your flag weight. It's not a problem until you notice that your flags are *consistently* being marked as invalid.

Keep up the good work in trying to flag off-topic questions! But in the future, please keep in mind that old questions shouldn't generally be flagged for migration--only flag them if one of the other flag reasons applies or if you think that they're hurting something by staying where they are. *New* questions that you notice would be better suited for another site are still fair game.

Comment: Something to think about: if the moderator *had* marked the flag as valid, how would @Guandalino have learned that this was a bad idea? Marking it as invalid means that, going forward, he won't waste time/flags doing that, and that ends up saving mods time as well.

Answer (score 3):

The question is off-topic on SO, so I'd regard an off-topic flag for that question as valid. It probably shouldn't be migrated as it is old and not exactly high quality.

If it was marked invalid, a moderator either disagreed, misread the question or flag, misclicked or something else happened that I didn't think of.

The moderators on SO go though hundreds of flags each day, the occasional flag will be erroneously marked as invalid. The 10 points flag weight really don't matter, just keep flagging, if you do it right your flag weight will increase.

Comment: +1 Oh right, even moderators are human being and can do mistakes!