# "testing the method" edit suggestion comment

Tags: discussion

I saw [*testing the method*](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/69696) given as the changelog entry for an anonymous edit suggestion that was pretty poor. I saw *testing the method* given as the changelog entry for a *different* poor edit suggestion within the last few days.

The coincidence seems unlikely.

Is this an eccentric anonymous user with a penchant for a funny phrase?
Is this a bot looking to see how closely we're paying attention?

I [tried my luck at data.se](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/104375/testing-the-method) but managed to fail.

Answer (score 2):

The data site is only updated periodically; the last update was June 6, so the edit suggestions you're talking about wouldn't be in there. I'm also not sure if rejected suggestions show up there. I don't see a type for suggestions; it's probably only approved suggestions that've actually become edits.

As for the edit, it's probably the same user, but two suggestions isn't exactly a lot; this was posted a couple hours after you: [Suggested Edits add "Thanks in Advance"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97136/suggested-edits-add-thanks-in-advance). This case is just a user who doesn't understand the purpose of edits. There's a feature request for [leaving feedback about rejected edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections), but for the moment there isn't much you can do (especially since the submitter is anonymous).