# Have temporary editing bans for rejected edits been removed?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I've done a fair number of reviews this morning, and have repeatedly rejected one particular user's edits as they've been very minor (i.e., changing "i" to "I" and adding newlines). So far, I've rejected at least 10 edits from this user.

My question is, why is this user still able to edit anything?

According to the answers and information from previous (albeit, outdated) questions, including [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91323/why-is-the-ban-for-too-many-rejected-edits-so-lengthy) and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104817/should-users-be-penalized-for-rejected-suggested-edits), indicate that after a certain number of edits, users are barred from editing, yet after many rejections from myself alone, all in the last couple hours, this user is still editing posts *as I write this question*. So far, he's almost hit the rep cap today for edits alone, no other contributions (he has received 168 rep so far today), likely from other reviewers accepting his minor edits.

Is there still a limit on the number of rejected edits you get before you're barred from editing? If not, why was it removed, and is there a possibility that it can it be added back in?

**Edit:** According to `Bart` in the comments, the edit ban is still active, so I guess a more appropriate question is what is the new limit for bans or how is it calculated?

Comment: Also, on an unrelated note, would it have been inappropriate to post a link to the user's profile in my question? Just wondering.

Comment: Nope, the bans still seem to be active. In fact, we have had a discussion with an edit-banned user this very day.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Do you happen to know the number of rejected edits needed for a ban off-hand?

Comment: No clue whatsoever. Sorry. I don't even know if rejections from a single user can have someone edit-banned.

Comment: It takes 2 reject votes to reject a suggested edit, so are you sure that other reviewers aren't approving the suggested edits that you're rejecting?

Comment: A number of rejection votes I made had the `1` notification next to "too minor" indicating someone else had also voted to reject it. But it's true that I'm not entirely sure how many have _actually_ been rejected.

Comment: Wow. That user suggested 70 edits over the past two hours (and his history doesn't even stop there). Based on the most recent 20, 95% get approved, though several are 2 accept vs 1 reject.

Comment: @PopularDemand Admittedly, some of his reviews are good, but most of the ones I've reviewed have needed to be edited because they weren't substantive on their own or were just flat out pointless. Looking through his history, I agree, a number of his suggestions have at least one rejection vote alongside the two accept votes. Also, he hit the rep cap about 25 minutes ago, and has since stopped suggesting edits. I think he's gaming edit rep. I can't believe that with almost 100 suggested edits in 6 hours, he didn't get enough rejections to get a ban.

Comment: I didn't even look at the quality of his edits. Partially because that would have slowed me down, but mostly because the ban algorithm only looks at approvals and rejections, not actual quality. If only it could do that, we wouldn't need human reviewers.... (Balpha! It's 2012! Where are my flying cars and smart edit review algorithms?)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a reference, my own [experience](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) about a year ago has been that six rejections can trigger ban:

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJWwR.png]

Comment: I wonder if 6 is the number for everyone. It probably is. Unless someone tells me otherwise, thanks, +1/accept.

Comment: I would guess that it's in the format _m_ rejections per _n_ time units. It wouldn't make sense to ban someone with, say, 250 good suggestions and six bad ones over a period of two months.

Answer (score -4):

Absolutely not. I am currently banned from tag wiki edits due to submitting information clearly marked as being from another source. The citation was not obvious to some editors, and thus the submissions were automatically rejected. I suspect the automatic rejections also had something to do with my low reputation.

Also, more specifically, my temporary ban was initially for a period of seven (7) days (because that's fair and equitable to a new editor obviously trying to improve the site instead of posting penis-pill spam edits).

I checked my activity log, and I submitted four tag wiki edit submissions (within the span of an hour or two) that were automatically rejected before the reasonable ban kicked in.

**So the most recent evidence shows that four edit rejections in a span of an hour or so will result in a ban for 7 days.**

Comment: Your reputation is not reduced because of suggested edits; it can only increase (by 2 each time a suggestion is accepted). Neither were the rejections automatic; two reviewers had to vote for each rejection.

Comment: Nor does reputation figure into the acceptance or rejection of a suggested edit. That is purely based on the content of that edit.

Comment: @JoshCaswell & Bart I think he's saying that because he had low rep the reviewers were less inclined to accept his changes.  It's an inherently un-provable assertion either way.

Comment: @Servy That's what I assumed. And I think it's rubbish. His particular suggested edits have been broadly discussed. So I won't do the same again here.

Comment: The suggested edit stats say "5 edit suggestions approved, and 6 edit suggestions rejected". So it appears that 6 is still the cutoff.