# completely superfluous edit

Tags: support, rejected-edits

I suggested an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24942649) to an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59481178/lsb-encryption-and-decryption/59481908#59481908).

The suggestion basically makes the code appliable to different image and message sizes.
This is the reason of rejection I get:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

After spending hours on this issue [<sup>[1]</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284255/is-a-superfluous-edit-really-a-reason-to-reject-it) [<sup>[2]</sup>](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287018/is-the-language-in-this-edit-rejection-too-strong) [<sup>[3]</sup>](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/242159/the-new-edit-rejection-message-for-no-improvement-whatsoever-sounds-too-hostil/242160#242160), my current opinion is as follows:

- The reason for rejection is not *completely* but *superfluously* harsh.
- I agree with the bumping back to front page part. Minor edit may be an alternative solution which may result, I don't know, other issues. I don't want to carry the whole discussion here.
- Something like *low-impact edit* may explain the reasoning better to me, as a newcomer. At least **it would be more meaningful the first time I see it**.
- At the end, the waste of time here is my effort to understand the situation here. I could totally understand something like *this edit does not deserve 2-rep*. But I would accept that anyway. Maybe an option for the reviewer to accept under no reputation condition?
- Finally, is the edit really not *more accurate*, with regards to the 3rd person? I think the algorithm becomes more perceptible and applicable to the reader. Why not to improve it?

Comment: The section "*I disagree with the reasons why my edit was rejected. What can I do?*" of our FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) addresses your question.

Comment: Here on this site, Meta Stack Exchange, we can only address things as they generally apply to the network of Stack Exchange sites, so there isn't much to say *here* other than what's in the FAQ I linked. If you want further information about your specific case, you'll have to ask on the per-site meta (Meta Stack *Overflow*) instead of here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say this:

> “After spending hours on this issue…”

This is the real problem: Why are you talking the rejection of one edit so personally?

I mean you say this:

> “The suggestion basically makes the code applicable to different image and message sizes.”

This is all in your opinion. Looking at [the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24942649) I see is an attempt by you to rewrite someone’s core answer content to make it fit your ideas of what is “better.” I program, I edit here and I have looked at your edit and I have no clue why you are “spending hours” on this.

My suggestion would be do one of the following:

1. **Comment**: In a comment suggest an edit to the answer and set your case there.
2. **Answer**: In many cases — especially when a post is old and might be out of date or you simply have a different PoV — you can absolutely post your own answer that even borrows from another answer and improves it to your liking. Even if there is an accepted answer, another PoV is typically always welcome as long as it has some rationale.

That said, my take on the question is your complaint is trivial because the edit is trivial and it should not be taken personally.