# In the page for the suggestions, show which ones have been approved, and which ones have been rejected

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

The old user profile showed the suggestions that were rejected, and the ones that were approved. Now the suggestion page just says "suggested," which is quite obvious, as I am seeing the suggestion page.

[image: screenshot]

Could we not have an indication of which suggestions were approved, and which suggestions were rejected, in the same way it is visible in the review tab?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This makes a lot of sense - I would like to see stats for suggested edits somewhere on the user page as well ("312 suggested edits, 160 approved, 151 rejected, 1 pending").

Comment: Ah, I was just looking through your posted questions for it :) I don't know the rules on meta about cross posting, but if you posted it here, I'd upvote it.

Comment: It also should show rejection reasons as suggested in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections

Comment: Official response regarding implementing this here: [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been implemented.

> [image: screenshot]

Now, *rejected edit* and *approved edit* are used where *suggested edit* was before used.