# Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, recent-activity

**Issue 1:**
I find it a bit irritating that when I click the Improve button and further edit it, even if I mark it as helpful, only Community takes the credit for the approval. I know the topic itself will contain the link to the suggested edit, but my activity history only says that I made an edit, and not approved a suggested edit. The same holds true for marking one as unhelpful. The activity history should say I rejected an edit, and then made an additional edit. I know it's not often, but sometimes I do try to go back to a suggested edit I've rejected, but when I improved *and* rejected, it's not traceable for me as it doesn't show in my history *or* in the question's revision history. So if I don't remember what user suggested it, it's lost to me.

This issue also plagues the [Proofreader and Reviewer badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122434) which are awarded for approving and rejecting suggested edits, which essentially you *have* done, you're just not receiving credit for it. I suggest that when I mark an edit as helpful or not helpful, both me *and* Community be listed as the approvers or rejecters, unless another user is already listed in the appropriate place.

**Update:** Here is [**an excellent example**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124141/is-there-a-way-to-suggest-a-decision-by-community-may-be-wrong) of the confusion this causes.

**Update 2:** Also, when improving a post and marking it as "not helpful", it would be nice to be able to [add a rejection reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123718/allow-adding-a-reject-reason-when-marking-an-edit-as-not-helpful-in-the-improv) along with it.

---

**Issue 2:**
Expanding off the idea that users need more notice for suggested edits that get rejected, the activity history page is much too useless when it comes to listing the suggested edits a user has made. Literally all it does is list them. A user still has to click through to each one in order to find out if it was approved or rejected, or even if it's still pending. Take, for example, this screen shot of the suggested edit history:

[image: suggested edit history]

Is it really necessary to say I suggested a suggested edit? Really? Of course I suggested it, **it's a suggested edit**. This isn't [tautology club](http://xkcd.com/703/)!

A good way to fix this would be to change the second "suggested" word into one of: pending, approved, or rejected. This would be a quick way to tell which edits have been approved or rejected and which ones are still pending. Users would be able to target out rejected edits and review them for the reasons. Something like this:

[image: revised suggested edit history]

Comment: I think the "Rejected" one could profit from showing the _reasons_ why the edit suggestion was rejected. I put effort into those...

Comment: This just bit me when looking at a user's history - I thought all the suggested edits were still in the queue.  I WILL FIX THIS ASAP!

Comment: It would also be nice if rejected was red and approved was green

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Due to query constraints and ease of localization, I opted to use your initial suggestion:

<kbd>[image: extra suggested edit info]</kbd>

This will be in the next build, going out now.

Comment: Just so you know, this update broke the reviews sort of their activity. See [this profile](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1141395/%E4%BA%9A%E5%8E%86%E5%B1%B1%E5%A4%A7?tab=activity&sort=reviews). It used to display what action they did on the suggested edit like all the other items in that list. It now displays "approved/rejected/pending edit" like the new view for the suggestions sort. The action they took is more relevant when trying to browse through that list.

Comment: Doh, that's what I get for trying to save some code.  Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Nice. Shame it took almost 3 years.

Answer (score 21):

I like where this is heading. Issue 1 has now been resolved with the update to the new review system, where an Edit action is now recorded under your profile and shows on the suggested edit itself, so credit is given to you and Community, like so:

> [image: Edit by animuson, Approved by Community]

However, it seems that we're still not shown an Approved/Rejected mark next to suggested edits when viewing our list of suggestions in our profile. This is peculiar because the people reviewing have this information listed in *their* list of reviews, like so:

> [image: Reviews by me, one Approved, one Edited]

Could this same layout not be applied to the suggestions list, showing Approved, Rejected, or Pending next to each item?

Comment: Along with Approved, Rejected, and Pending, I think that they could also use Improved and Rewritten.  Improved would mean that a helpful edit was edited further.  A Rewritten would mean that a non-helpful edit was edited rather than rejected.  All of these headings should have a (Why?) link next to them that shows any feedback from the reviewers.

Comment: And yet another situation to cover:  rollback.  If a user's edit is accepted but later rolled back, the Accept should change to a Rolled Back.

Comment: @Brythan That's getting carried away. The status is meant to be an action from the review. An external rollback is not even related to the review panel whatsoever. As far as Improved or Rewritten- if they go that way I'd prefer they both just be combined as Edit to match the existing actions. But really I'd rather them see an Approved or Rejected there; the fact that it got Edited doesn't seem all that relevant when browsing my list of reviews.

Comment: I would argue that the purpose of the message is to give feedback to the editor.  The review is irrelevant to the editor except in that it can give feedback.  A rollback also offers a chance for feedback and should be marked.  In regards to your other point, I agree that people want to know if their edits were Accepted or Rejected.  I believe that Improved and Rewritten do that.  They also communicate that the edit was found wanting but that the issue was addressed.  Should reviewers reject mostly good edits so as to leave rejection feedback?  Improved/Rewritten feedback is better there IMO.