# Explaining why a suggested edit is not helpful

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Allow adding a reject reason when marking an edit as “not helpful” in the improve screen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123718/allow-adding-a-reject-reason-when-marking-an-edit-as-not-helpful-in-the-improv)

When you choose to improve a suggested edit, there's a checkbox ("suggested edit was helpful") that determines whether the edit is accepted or rejected before the improvement. Sometimes, I'd like to send a message back to the editor explaining why I marked the edit as unhelpful, so the editor in question can improve his/her editing habits. Could there please be an option for that?

EDIT: This is specifically for the "improve and reject" feature. I'd like the same functionality as a rejection message of "Other". Sorry, the "message" part is ambiguous.

Comment: Reject the edit, and then make your own edit.  If their edit was useful enough to keep and improve, you should probably mark it helpful.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It wasn't helpful, but I'd like to make an immediate improvement and reject it unilaterally. That's pretty much the point of the "suggested edit was helpful" checkbox.

Comment: @random: No, that isn't the question. I've edited it to be a little more clear, hopefully.

Comment: @random - I think the request here is that the feedback mechanism for an outright reject of an edit can't be applied to a post that was improved but the original edit rejected as unhelpful.

Comment: Got a re-open from me although I think the feedback here possibly comes from looking at the edit you made instead of theirs quite often. I.e. your edit says "this is what you should have done instead".

Comment: You don't get notifications on rejected edits now, so this would be extending a feature change that hasn't been done

Comment: @random: I don't want a notification. I just want the message to show up in the suggested edit summary as the rejection reason.