# Suggested Edit: Expanded Editor Stats

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits

I recently started going back in and double checking on my Suggested Edits (since I don't have enough Rep to edit without approval yet).  At first I hunted around and saw some stuff posted here about how/where to find my list of edits/suggestions.  After clicking into my profile and finding it, I was concerned to see how many suggested edits I had rejected.

I found this number out by clicking into the first edit on my activity stream, and clicking 
"More" to see more information about the rejection.  I saw `Community` rejected it, and hence I came over to Meta to figure out why/what this meant.  I have since found out that `Community` rejections are a different beast and are not "negative" in a way.

These are suggestions I have in addition to ones I already [found here on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122581/improving-how-suggested-edits-are-displayed-in-your-activity-history).

**Problem 1:** Editor Stats, rejected by Community count

How it is displayed now

`UserA had X edit suggestions approved, and Y edit suggestions rejected`.

Suggestion

`UserA had X edit suggestions approved, and Y edit suggestions rejected (Z by Community)`.

This number at first shocked me when I saw how large it was.  It could be very useful from a statistics standpoint to see how many rejects one has from the Community.  Since a Community "reject" is not really "negative", it would be helpful to see that distinction in the stats to quickly see how many rejections were valid reasons.  The way it is now, a user could be discouraged to improve by seeing a large reject count, when in theory a Community rejection is a good thing and is positive improvement, since the Community "agrees" the edits need to be made and the original editor is on the right track.

**Problem 2:** Suggested Edits list is not futher filterable

This closely relates to Issue 2 from the related Meta post I liked above.  Having a better display would make the Suggested Edits list easier to parse through.  I think another filter could help as well.  Being able to quickly click a filter to display only `"Approved"`, `"Rejected by Community"`, or `"Rejected"` would let users see more information about their edits.  Right now if an edit was rejected even with the suggestions in the other post, the user has to click through all of them and hunt through the list to find the ones that were Rejected for valid reasons.  Having a large number means a user has to click through ALL their edits (if display is different, all the rejects) to find valid reasons to fix their editing in the future.

Being able to quickly filter on true rejects, a user doesn't need to hunt, search, or waste time looking through to find new edits that were rejected.  The quick finding of these rejections will help a user find what they can do to improve their edits in the future.  For someone like myself who just went back in to start looking into my edits, the list is long and looking to find ### rejects is like looking for a needle in a haystack.  When trying to improve on my edits finding the actual issues I need to address is impossible (figuratively) to find in the current system.

Comment: There are two main reasons the community user would reject an edit.  One, a reviewer improved your post and felt that it wasn't helpful.  In this case, this is a sign that you made a bad edit.  The other option is that your edit simply conflicted with the edit of another user who submitted one right after yours without even knowing you suggested an edit.  If you "lost" the race then your edit is rejected, but it may have not been a bad edit.  The latter is much less common then the former.

Comment: @Servy I agree with you that the first case is most likely a bad edit, but I've been frustrated by that second case. I think it would be useful if we created a better term for 'overriden' edits.

Comment: @p.s.w.g True.  The second case should perhaps have some third option beside "rejected", not count towards edit bans, be displayed differently, etc.  I thought I remembered seeing a suggestion for that a while back, but it didn't really go anywhere.

Comment: @Servy one way or another, seeing expanded info on these reasons would help.  Was my edit improved by Community, or did I lose the race?  The current system doesn't provide 1. enough feedback to help improve future edits. 2. makes it very difficult to find the actual feedback if any real reject reasons/feedback are given.  The list is not filterable and makes it a large burden to try and improve.  A system like this is designed to make people without the required edit rep to learn, and right now the learning is tricky.  We shouldn't be hindering users who want to improve edits over time.