# Could we make it easier for people to see *just* their rejected "suggested edits"?

Tags: feature-request, suggested-edits, rejection-reasons

Why is it so difficult to see rejected suggested edits? If there is a way to view just the rejected suggested edits or to sort by rejected vs. accepted, that would be really helpful.

I want to be able to understand more about why my edits are rejected, but it's not very easy to find the reasons for rejection. This is partly because it's not all that easy to see *which suggestions* were rejected in the first place.

If you do see that there was a rejection and the link shows up, as was suggested here: [Decision on rejected edits should be displayed as a notification to the editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120624/decision-on-rejected-edits-should-be-displayed-as-a-notification-to-the-editor) and as I think actually does happen, that seems to be the easiest way to find the rejected edit along with its reasons. But, what if you wish to look back and see more about what reasons were given over a series of rejections?

Making it easier to spot rejected suggestions would help: [Improving how suggested edits are displayed in your activity history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/122581/269695) but it would be even better if I could see all of the reasons for rejection together so that I can see any patterns. This could be particularly helpful if the reasons for rejection were custom reasons so that I might get more useful information about what's going on.

Comment: Perhaps not what you are looking for, but there is a Data.SE query [my rejected edits](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/45755/my-rejected-edits).

Comment: What best worked for me (in my time) was to suggest the edit and wait to see if it was going to be approved or rejected (which is quick on SO, at least). If it was rejected, I'd change the strategy right away instead of suggesting many edits in a row, and then going back to see if they were approved or not.

Comment: @Thursday - This is helpful, but not exactly simple. I think it's not something a newcomer would find or be able to use meaningfully. Once I ran the query, if I looked at a suggested edit, I would have to run the query again (AFAICT).

Comment: @AndreSilva - That's a good strategy. But, it still does not allow a user to easily see their rejections in one place along with the reasons.

Comment: @PrairieProf This seems like a request for a feature for viewing your rejected suggested edits easily, so I've retagged this as [feature-request].

Comment: @doppelgreener - Thanks! I appreciate the help. I am hoping to inspire changes that will make newcomers feel empowered to learn from participating in the site, and I guess it is ultimately a feature request.