# Multiple edits to correct capitalisation

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, review

Going through the /review/ list on SO it seems that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400291/sidratul-muntaha?tab=activity) suggested a number of edits which simply updated the first letter of the title to a capital letter. I approved 2 until I saw that there were a number of them and now I'm not sure if this counts as a [pedantic edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections/79761#79761).

In cases like this, should the edits be approved or rejected for being pedantic - as the edit doesn't really add value or clarification to the question.

Comment: If they capitalize all/most of the instances that need capitalization (and not capitalize words that don't need to), then I would consider approve such edits.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I actually consider even minor edits in the title to be a good idea, having titles with bad spelling or grammar stay around makes the site look worse. Having a frontpage with bad grammar and spelling just makes a site look unprofessional.

That said, the specific edits you mention are still bad edits. Not because they just fix the uppercase in the title, but **because they leave all the other problems those posts have unedited**. I would consider an edit that does nothing but correct the spelling of the title acceptable, but only if the post has no other problems. This situation is pretty rare, but it happens occasionally.

Comment: `because they leave all the other problems those posts have unedited` +1

Comment: _"having titles with bad spelling..."_, like these [1](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+title%3A%22javacript%22), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+title%3A%22javascrpt%22), [3](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+title%3A%22javascrit%22), [4](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[javascript]+title%3A%22javscript%22)?

Comment: I agree with points that both you and @jeff have made. In the example I listed, the edits left the problems in the post, but just added a capital letter into the title - those I believe should be rejected.

Answer (score 9):

Incorrect capitalization in the title of a question does not decrease its readers' ability to comprehend the question, nor does it in any way make detract from the value of the question. Therefore, I would classify this edit as pedantic and reject it.

These edits seem more like desperate attempts to gain reputation rather than sincere efforts to improve the quality of the question.