# Add "reject question" option to Suggested Edit review queue

Tags: feature-request

Going through the Suggested Edits review queue, I've run into a fair number of questions where my reaction was basically that the edit was simply irrelevant, because the question was simply off-topic ([one example](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1198339)).

This might be a fine question on Ask Ubuntu, but at least to me, it seems quite clearly off-topic for SO. I don't really want to skip it (there's clearly something that should be done) but none of accepting, rejecting, nor improving the edit is really the right thing to do either.

Could we expose things like the "close" button so we can deal with questions like this appropriately?

Comment: No, I don't think we need such an option. In the rare cases where it really applies just add custom rejection message.

Comment: related info: ["turd polishing"](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf8&oe=utf8&q=site:meta.stackoverflow.com+%22turd+polishing%22) (A rejection reason has also been (perhaps jokingly) suggested for this situation [by Benjol](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections#comment278065_107930).)

Answer (score 7):

Editing is at the core of good Q&A, and one of the things that moderators do before migrating any question is to make sure that it's the best quality possible so that they don't dump garbage onto another site.

Thus, closed questions, including off-topic questions, can and should be edited and improved. Not only does this make them more visible, but it makes it easier to judge the content for the content itself, without all the noise from spelling issues, language barriers, and poor formatting. This ensures that a question that *should* be migrated will be more likely to *get* migrated by busy moderators who may only have a few moments to glance at the post and make a snap judgement.

In a broader sense, it's a good idea to edit any question that contains these sort of issues. When you clear out the cobwebs, it becomes much easier to tell if the question is constructive, loo localized, not a real question, or if there is some helpful comment you, or someone else, could leave the asker to help improve the post. For the same reasons as in the migration example, editing out the distractions makes it much easier for the community to make a fair judgement of the post.

In short, if you see a suggested edit that substantially improves a post, just give the question the benefit of the doubt and improve it. Hope this helps!

Lastly, I believe the inability to close questions in the suggested edits queue is [status-by-design](/questions/tagged/status-by-design), as the Stack Exchange team feels that reviewers should focus on one thing at a time. Instead, users navigating the close vote review queue will likely have this covered for you. ;)  Also, consider that when you approve the edit, the question bumps to the top of the main page, where it will be seen by countless Stack Exchange users, many of whom will take action if they agree the post should be closed.