# Edit queue: Feedback on rejected edits

Tags: feature-request, edits, moderation, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pending Approvals - Reasons to Reject](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-reasons-to-reject)

On a number of edit queue entries, I've rejected a well-intentioned edit for reasons I'd like to explain to the editor (eg, "You should voice your concerns in a comment rather than editing someone else's post outright without asking first."). However, with the current system, the only feedback I can give is an accept or reject. It would be helpful if edit queue moderators could give some sort of feedback when they reject an edit, to help the editor make better edits in the future.

Comment: I see your point, but "convince me" a comment on the question would be enough?

Comment: @Trufa Well, one possible convincing argument could be that [we don't yet know if a comment will actually reach that editor](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77784/are-users-who-have-a-suggested-edit-rejected-valid-targets-for-comment-replies).

Comment: @Grace yeah, but you could still add your comment and other's allowed to vote could see it too. This way if you support it or don't support it you can say why.

Comment: @Pete While it gives feedback, it isn't guaranteed to reach the edit suggestor in question, which I think it the goal here. If comment replies would work, I imagine that would be the best scenario.

Comment: I would really like to see this feature.

Comment: @Grace thanks, I will see how that goes!

Answer (score 5):

Giving feedback on suggested edits to the editor should be useful no matter if the edit subsequently got approved or rejected. The people editing are (by definition) new to editing and therefore likely to make non-optimal edits. Some feedback could be helpful there.