# Can I know who have accepted my edit or rejected it or reason for rejection?

Tags: discussion, questions, edits, suggested-edits

Assume that I have edited one question. Due to reputation limitation my edit goes for review. There either it will be accepted or will be rejected. So can I know who have accepted/rejected my edit? Also can I know the reason for rejection? Also sometimes when I edit some question it shows my edited question, but it shows someone else's name in *edited by*. Why so?

Comment: possible (partial) dupe of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77949/edit-queue-feedback-on-rejected-edits or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-reasons-to-reject

Comment: also you may want to post the second part (incorrect attribution) as a seperate question under the 'bug' tag - that shouldn't happen. Links to a specific example would probably be helpful for debugging too

Comment: Lead for one instance of knowing the reason for rejection: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78064

Comment: @Peter, that doesn't have anything to do with rejection reasons...?

Comment: @bdonlan: no, just a way to get some information why one particular edit suggestion was rejected -from you!

Comment: @Peter - oh, indeed. Unfortunately, I can't see the reject anymore and don't remember exactly what suggested edit it was :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The approval process does maintain a history of your proposed edits and an audit trail of  who reviewed the edit and whether they chose to accept or reject. For example here are [three](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2292) [recent](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2297) [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2298) you suggested.

Since all three were approved, you do appear in the edit history for [each](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4906104/revisions) of [those](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4906384/revisions) [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4906396/revisions).

The suggested edit process is still in development, so there is no easy way for you to find the link to your suggested edits if they are rejected. They don't show up on your activity page (and we don't know yet if they ever will).

Only the most recent editor is displayed on the post itself. The reason your name doesn't show up on the post even though you edited it is because someone else has made further edits to the post. (And in one case the OP rolled back what you had changed.) You can see the revision history by clicking the time next to the word `edited...` on the post.

Comment: thnx buddy for explanation.