# Possibility to add a comment to a rejected suggested edit

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections)

I would like to see the possibility to add a comment to why I reject a proposed edit. This would serve two purposes:

1. Indicate to other reviewers why I thought that the edit should be rejected.
2. The comment could be used to tell the original editor what I found wrong with the edit

I find that new users sometimes tend to edit the question to contain their own answer, something like:

> P.S. From @SomeUser:
>
> You can also do this and that bla bla bla

So I would definitely like to see some way of communicating to the user that there was nothing wrong with what was written, only that it was written in a wrong place. I think that being able to add a short comment to my reject-vote would help educate newcomers.

Let me know what you think.

Comment: While I agree that it can be useful to provide feedback if someone accidentally was making the wrong kind of edits. In most of the other cases, I think it just adds overhead to the process.

Comment: Related: [Are users who have a suggested edit rejected valid targets for @comment replies?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77784/are-users-who-have-a-suggested-edit-rejected-valid-targets-for-comment-replies), and especially [waffles' answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77784/are-users-who-have-a-suggested-edit-rejected-valid-targets-for-comment-replies/78332#78332): *[...]Do we need commenting on the suggested-edit permalink page? Perhaps. If we add that it would complicate things and is yet another area for us to moderate.*

Comment: @Ivo, yeah I agree. It should not be mandatory that's for sure. An alternative approach is to have more than one reject button, like `Reject - should have been an answer` and `Reject - bad formatting` besides the generic `Reject` button.

Comment: Apart from a reject comment (which I'd like, just like a regular revision comment for any other action I perform), I think it would also be nice to have an overview of the edits one proposed. Right now, editors cannot easily tell if if edits are still awaiting peer review, have been rejected, or if something silently failed. (But, this all still being in development, I'm quite sure we'll see such overview soon.)

Comment: (Good find, @Jon. I renamed that one to "Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections"; though I did see it linked on other questions, I never thought it was about this very topic!)

Comment: @Jon, @Arjan, I feel like this question should be kept open: it expresses the problem much better. Shoban's is kind of lost in the anecdote: as demonstrated by the fact that most people seem to have answered his anecdote. It's the title which counts, and changing the other title happened too late, in my opinion.

Comment: @Ivo I have rejected nearly 30 edits already (out of ~80 total), and in each case editor probably could benefit from knowing the reason. Also, I saw the situations where seeing previous rejection comment could affect the choice of other approvers.