# Edit Review : Rejection on the basis of one problem

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I have just rejected an otherwise good edit because one word, in my opinion, went too far -['half-way' was changed to 'half-baked'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/284921/is-dependency-injection-possible-with-a-wpf-appliction) - [a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79088/possibility-to-add-a-comment-to-a-rejected-suggested-edit) may have been just the thing, but what do others suggest?

EDIT: As an aside, can Accept / Reject ping-pong?

Comment: Accept and then edit yourself?

Comment: @Simon I did think of that, but it did not seem to be quite right, however, it is certainly an option.

Comment: Accept, then edit or reject and then edit... Either one is fair game. Personally, I'd make the choice based on which result would be more acceptable if I *didn't* follow up with an edit. At least he didn't change it to "half-assed"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the edit has a single problem, but is otherwise a good edit, I will open a new window on the editing question, accept the edit, refresh the new window, and fix the single problem.

If the edit has a number of problems, or [changes the technical content of the post,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78845/should-suggested-edits-change-the-technical-content-of-a-post) I reject the edit.  If the post still needs editing, and I have time, I edit the post myself.

More than half of the tag wiki edits that I approve have to be further edited.  Which is not a complaint, by the way.  There are many tag wikis that are getting filled in with good content because someone (no matter their rep) cares enough to post a tag summary and description.

Answer (score 4):

You now have the option of "Improve", which would address this issue.