# Tag Wiki Finally Approved; Any Way To See Previous Rejection Reasons?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, rejected-edits

After a few attempts, the tag wiki I created for [json-lib](/questions/tagged/json-lib) was finally approved, though it's just a copy-paste of the same rejected text I submitted before.

Is there any way to see comments on why my previous submissions were rejected?

(Full tag wiki text available at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/json-lib/info.)

Comment: The excerpt didn't really describe what the library does, so I modified it a bit.

Comment: Also, users are not asked for a rejection reason, so there's no way to know why a suggested edit was rejected.

Comment: Alas, users are not asked for a rejection reason, so we cannot report that a tag was defined way too narrowly or read too much like a sales report.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no commenting for why a suggested edit is rejected.

This has come up a few times, so consider reading the following related posts:

- [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77875/)
- [Are users who have a suggested edit rejected valid targets for @comment replies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77784)

(Really?  You're submitting the exact same text that you've submitted before that's been rejected?  If something got rejected, even without a reason, you can probably figure out some way to improve it.)

Comment: Any suggestions on improving the tag wiki?  A link to an exemplary question/answer on the topic doesn't seem to apply.