# Allow pinging a user who suggested a rejected edit

Tags: feature-request, comment-replies, rejected-edits

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) version of [Are users who have a suggested edit rejected valid targets for @comment replies?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77784/are-users-who-have-a-suggested-edit-rejected-valid-targets-for-comment-replies)

If a user suggested an edit which was later rejected, they should still be manually pingable on the post.

Answer (score 0):

Comments should be used to request clarification and add details to improve *the post*. The system should be the one to help educate users about rejected suggested edits, not other users in the comments. It's distracting and doesn't help improve the original post.

So unless you have another usecase where a rejected editor would need to be pinged, I vote nay.

Comment: I disagree. This question was asked because on Mi Yodeya, someone suggested an edit to remove a tag from one of my questions. This user was not active in chat, so I had to drop a comment on one of his old posts to tell him why I rejected his edit. "System education" doesn't work in this case and others like it.