# Question edits that contain answers from other users

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Suggested edits that add an answer to the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77771/suggested-edits-that-add-an-answer-to-the-question)
>   [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections)

In the moderator tools, I see a rash of pending edits from users that simply edit the original poster's code to be correct, rather than answering the question.  This ranges from a direct edit of a few broken lines of code, to typing an entire answer at the end of the original question.

I just obtained 10k today, so I don't know if this has been going on for awhile, but from what I have seen today, it seems like a common issue.

Does this warrant some instructional verbiage being added to the edit page?  If so, can that be added?

In the mean time, I have been rejecting these kinds of edits.  Is there any way to leave a note to the person who suggested the edit, explaining what the problem was?

**Edit:**  It seems at least one other person has noticed this phenomenon:  [Pending approvals: allow for adding reasons to rejections](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77875/pending-approvals-allow-for-adding-reasons-to-rejections/96257#96257)

Comment: Yes, this has been going on for quite some time. Particularly with anonymous or < 5 rep users proposing these types of edits. Rejecting them is the correct approach; currently there is no way to leave comments on edits. This is pretty much a nonsensical action anyway -- *any* user can already post answers to questions. If it's an actual answer, they should post it as one. The UI already leads them directly to this, as do all of the FAQ pages. I'm not sure what you think we should change.