# What should I do about a question where the OP has quoted an answer in the question but not accepted it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8566/best-way-to-access-a-control-on-another-form-in-winforms) question, which is fairly old, has 2 very good answers (with a good amount of up-votes), and the OP has stated in his question that both of the answers are acceptable. Yet they have not accepted either and simply left a note in their original question about the "correct" answer.

Is there anything that needs to be looked at here? Should I comment that the OP should accept an answer if they have one? Should I flag it?

Comment: That seems to be a very old question, and the OP hasn't come back in more than half a year. I don't think there's a very good chance of having an answer to that question accepted.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I have seen this situation occur on more recent post's as well though, just meant that to be a general example. The issue being active people posting the answers to the questions within their question, instead of accepting the posted answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a **very old** question from times when they didn't have a lot of the rules and features we have today. I don't think they even had commenting on answers back then, so editing was the only way to "summarize" your answer in the end.

Nowadays, we don't allow answers in the question body at all. If the answer that was edited into the question already exists below, just edit it out. If it's not, you can:

1. @notify the OP requesting that they move the answer into an actual answer and remove it from the question body.
2. Cut the answer from the question body and post it yourself as a new *community wiki* answer.

Answer (score 8):

> Should I comment that the OP should accept an answer if they have one?

A *nice* comment to *guide* a new user is always an option. It should explain how the system works, nothing more.

But this question is from 2008 and the OP visisted SO on Oct 26 '11 for the last time, so it's unlikely to have any effect in this case.

> Should I flag it?

**Never** flag for anything related to accepting answers.

Users are free to accept whichever answer they want (or none at all).

Comment: Don't flag for anything related to *accepting* answers, not *accepted* answers - as some *accepted* answers may be subject to moderation in extreme cases.

Comment: That's what I intended to write. Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do when a question quotes a given answer is to remove that quote. If the question is referring to the given answer just to say that it doesn't work, or doesn't give the expected result, that is fine; probably the answer should not be quoted, in that case, but a reference to that answer is fine.

As the OP has not been seen, lately, commenting would probably not have any effect. Flagging the question would not have any purpose, as moderators cannot do anything about accepted answers, except deleting an accepted answer (which would cause the question not to have an accepted answer), but that is not the case. A moderator could just remove the quoted answer, but that is something any user can do, and the flag would be rejected as it doesn't inform the moderators of something that requires their intervention.