# Should this solution edited into question be rolled back?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just noticed [How do I generate a KML file in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952667/solved-how-to-output-a-simple-c-asp-net-generated-kml-file?rq=1) in the related question sidebar while browsing today.

I know updating the question to reflect the solution is discouraged.  Questions should remain a question, and solutions (even from the OP) belong in the answers, but given how much changed in the final revision and given the age of the question and popularity of the question, is rolling back, editing, and entering the solution (as CW) in the answers appropriate in this case, or is this a historical issue that should be left alone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed it.  If you feel weird about making those sorts of edits, then you can flag to let a moderator know.

All in all, especially with the edit system, you should make those edits, and if someone thinks they shouldn't be made, they'll rollback the edits.  I wish people were more aggressive with edits, rather than waiting for someone else to do the work (I'm not saying you did that here, just that there's a culture that sometimes causes people to not make needed edits).

Comment: `just that there's a culture that sometimes causes people to not make needed edits` Probably due to major edit rejection from suggested edit...

Comment: Thanks George, it's probably a rep thing. I'm just a little uncomfortable radically editing questions (even when they are justified) that have been around longer than I've been active on the site.