# No flags left for moderator attention, how to inform about irregularities

Tags: discussion, flags

During a suggested edit review I noticed that a user [tried to remove the answer part of a question and added it as their own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17295005/1699210).

I could flag as "not welcome to comunity", but there would be no possibility to add a comment.

Comment: Go visit a chat room to solicit assistance from other users?

Comment: Could you link to the suggested edit instead of the post? When the edit was rejected, it will not show up in the revision history.

Comment: Why would you flag it as not welcome in our community? Does it offend you?

Comment: I would not do anymore, I have not been aware of the history, just felt not okay with extracting someones work as own answer. I am still learning ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually he did correct steps. He [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2380379) removing answer from the question which is correct. But unfortunately his suggestion was rejected. Only one thing he did wrong is he posted the answer without Community Wiki which he needed to do.

When you see a question where the OP has answered himself into the question itself. You should ask him to add his own answer and accept it. If he don't do that or don't response you then we should remove the answer from the question and should add a new answer with the CW checkmark.

In this case [@minitech asked him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229308/rails-3-devise-ldap-authenticatable-authorization-against-active-directory/17295005#comment-25050847) to move his answer from the question but he didn't response (as he has not visited the site since May 17).

Comment: Yeah, CW would solve this. Not delete worthy, and imo poster was trying to improve the site.

Comment: I agree with CW, but would feel adding as own answer like stealing.

Comment: @bummi - We should not feel like stealing because we first asked (request?) him to add his own answer. But after his ignorance if we post an answer on behalf of him (with CW) that is totally okay. And this is the purpose of a Q&A site and CW.

Comment: still not happy with the missing CW, but thanks for broadening my understanding.

Comment: @bummi - Don't worry I have flagged that answer to make it CW.

Comment: @hims056 I just noticed the answer below which was presumably deleted for the very same reason (not being CW), it had 4 upvotes...