# What to do when the OP posted the answer in a question edit but the question is closed?

Tags: discussion, edits, closed-questions

I know that [this question was asked before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74101/what-to-do-when-op-answers-his-her-own-question-in-an-edit), but this is a different situation.
[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21981445/jquery-submit-form-load-another-page) the OP asked something, then the question got closed. After this, he edited his question with the answer. I would comment him to post the content of his edit as an anwser, but he can't do that because the question is closed. Actually it is in the reopen queue because of his edit, but what to do if it will stay closed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit it out of the question, because answers shouldn't be in the question.

When this happens to a question closed as "unclear", as is the case here, it generally means that the question did not have enough information to determine the solution.  The OP had knowledge that they didn't share that they used to solve the problem.  In this case the best resolution is to edit the question into one that is answerable, by including whatever information the OP used to solve it that they did not share at first.  The question will then include enough information to solve the problem.  Then it can be reopened, and the answer posted as an answer.

Comment: Very few questions get reopened, unless a moderator does it.  If you edit out the answer, and then wait until the community gets around to opening it, that's almost never going to happen, thus the answer will get lost.

Comment: @MystereMan Well, it doesn't get lost, it will be in the edit history. It will be only almost invisible.

Comment: @MystereMan That's simply not true. The community reopens plenty of questions.  The vast majority of closed questions simply never get edits into sufficient shape as to warrant reopening.  Most that do tend to get reopened.  As for the value of the answer being lost in the event such editing doesn't take place; if the question is entirely unclear and the answer is heavily reliant on information not in the question, who would this information be of value to?  How would someone in the same situation even find the question, given that the relevant information isn't even there?

Comment: @Servy - Do you have any statistics on that?  How many questions are re-opened after edits vs those that don't?  Thing is, I can't think of a single case of this happening with any question I've participated in closing, and I've voted for many re-opens.  Getting enough re-open votes is unlikely unless the question gains a lot of exposure.

Comment: @MystereMan The vast majority of closed questions that are edited aren't edited into sufficient shape to warrant reopening.  Can you link to a question that should have been reopened due to an edit that wasn't?  As for statistics, you'd need Shog to come and give us those stats on the close queue, but I'm sure it does end up reopening quite a lot of questions, in absolute terms (perhaps not in percentage terms).